# Clearing autocomplete in select2 without closing dropdown

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-select2

Does anyone know how to have an option to clear the contents of the autocomplete field in select2 dropdown?  At the moment the User has to backspace to clear the text, which can by annoying when several search/selections are required.  A simple 'X' or (if not possible), a button next to the field would be good.  I've tried various combinations of `.select2-search--dropdown .select2-search__field` with trying to clear the search field, but have got nowhere and the dropdown always closes.  Fiddle shown below. Thanks.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css"></script>

<body class='bodyClass'>
  <div class="row">
    <select id="SteelList" name="SteelList" class="form-control select2-multiple">
      <option value="40">France</option>
      <option value="960">Spain</option>
      <option value="540">Italy</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</body>



  $(function() {

  var S2MultiCheckboxes = function(options, element) {
    var self = this;
    self.options = options;
    self.$element = $(element);
    var values = self.$element.val();
    self.$element.removeAttr('multiple');
    self.select2 = self.$element.select2({

      allowClear: true, // Puts little 'X' in top placeholder  
      //minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
      placeholder: options.placeholder,
      closeOnSelect: false,

      templateSelection: function() {
        return self.options.templateSelection(self.$element.val() || [], $('option', self.$element).length);
      },
      templateResult: function(result) {
        if (result.loading !== undefined)
          return result.text;
        return $('<div>').text(result.text).addClass(self.options.wrapClass);
      }
    }).data('select2');
    self.select2.$results.off("mouseup").on("mouseup", ".select2-results__option[aria-selected]", (function(self) {
      return function(evt) {
        var $this = $(this);

        var data = $this.data('data');

        if ($this.attr('aria-selected') === 'true') {
          self.trigger('unselect', {
            originalEvent: evt,
            data: data
          });
          return;
        }

        self.trigger('select', {
          originalEvent: evt,
          data: data
        });
      }
    })(self.select2));
    self.$element.attr('multiple', 'multiple').val(values).trigger('change.select2');
  }

  // ------------------------

  $.fn.extend({
    select2MultiCheckboxes: function() {
      var options = $.extend({
        placeholder: 'Choose elements',
        templateSelection: function(selected, total) {
          return selected.length + ' > ' + total + ' total';
        },
        wrapClass: 'wrap'
      }, arguments[0]);

      this.each(function() {
        new S2MultiCheckboxes(options, this);
      });
    }
  });

})

// ======================================

// Init script
$(function() {
  $('.select2-multiple').select2MultiCheckboxes({

    closeOnSelect: true,

    templateSelection: function(selected, total) {
      return "Select Country - Selected " + selected.length + " of " + total;
    }

  })

});




 .bodyClass {
 min-height: 100vh;
}

.select2-results__option .wrap:before {
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  color: #999;
  content: "\f096";
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.select2-results__option[aria-selected=true] .wrap:before {
  content: "\f14a";
}

.select2-container--default .select2-search--dropdown .select2-search__field {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.row {
  padding: 10px;
}

.select2-multiple,
.select2-multiple2 {
  width: 50%
}

.select2-results__group .wrap:before {
  display: none;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3hs4cf4n/

Answer (score 2):

Found an answer for clearing autocomplete fields of select2.This one is not the complete answer for your requirement,but may help you find a solution.

To clear a filed with id ="name", use the below code

```
$('#name').val(null).trigger('change');
```